# searching stackoverflow with case sensitive tag or string

Tags: discussion, search, stack-overflow

I am trying to search StackOverflow itself for questions with a tag or string matching "Curl" but not "cURL" ( for "Curl" the MIT web language now owned by Tokyo-based SCSK and not "cURL" )

Is there a way that I could tag to differentiate "Curl" from "curl", CURL and cURL ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl-language for this specific case.

Comment: @minitech: the answer here is to point to the separate tags for [cURL the library and commandline tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl) and [Curl the language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl-language).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I was about to, and thanks for the links :) [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104397/160410) does cover that too.