# Case Insensitive search for duplicate question

Tags: feature-request, search, duplicate-questions

It has happened many times on SO that while closing a question as duplicate, I vaguely remember the title of the duplicate question, but of course no one can exactly remember it word by word (including case-sensitiveness). And that has resulted in difficulties to find questions. Sometimes, I really get irritated and leave the question as opened, even though I know there is duplicate somewhere out there.

Can we make the title-search at least case-insensitive (that would make it little bit more intelligent)?

Comment: Hmm. Acording to this link [Add the option to do a case-sensitive search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27411) it is already *case insensitive* (the link is asking for *case sensitive* search to be *added*)

Comment: @DavidPostill Hmm. Strange that I felt this issue. Possibly the ordering the search results are different based on case.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you know the exact text or not when searching for duplicates you know exist they're [painfully difficult](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232242/help-us-find-duplicates-efficiently) to find.

Comment: @Iain Yes, that is what exactly I was talking about :( It's sad that it hasn't been taken up yet, or I don't know what's its status is.

Comment: @RohitJain It does not lead to sucking more people into the SE universe so it is no value to them. For all of their highfalutin words about quality all that really matters is clicks.

Answer (score 2):

According to this link [Add the option to do a case-sensitive search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27411) it is already *case insensitive* (the link is asking for *case sensitive* search to be *added*).

Evidence:

Searching meta for `case` and for `Case` return the same number of results ...

[image]

[image]